# Add a dynamic time for my label

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, label

I have a label in my grid

```
<Label Name="time"  Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1"   />
```

And then

```
 time.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

But it's static.

How can I make the time label update to represent the actual time?

Comment: You need something that runs behind the scene, prob a timer.

Comment: This post sounds like its what your looking for http://forums.asp.net/t/1528616.aspx/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the constructor of your page :

```
DispatcherTimer messageTimer = new DispatcherTimer(); 
messageTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(messageTimer_Tick); 
messageTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); 
messageTimer.Start();
```

and the messageTimer_Tick :

```
void messageTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    time.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Timer control to your page, which every one secound will update your GridView

Answer (score 0):

```
public Timer()
{
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); // Everytime timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
        timer.Interval = (1000) * (1);              // Timer will tick evert second
        timer.Enabled = true;                       // Enable the timer
        timer.Start();                              // Start the timer
}
```

Now every second the event will be launched and the following EventHandler will generate the current date and set this as the value of time.Content, which will cause the dynamic effect.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        time.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```